# J2ME to (PHP FB app) login and photo post

Tags: php, facebook, java-me, authentication

I would like to do a very simple J2ME app that will send photo to a facebook app and post a photo taken by the phone to facebook. Now the problem I am facing is that I cannot figure out a way of translating the browser login to a J2ME login through the PHP app without doing an automatic login on the PHP side. Apparently it's frowned upon to do a programmatic login so I am stuck. I could use the form data on the website with curl and try and automate the process but I don't know to what extent this is legal from FB's point of view. The app would be available for anyone so it's not a one user (that would have been doable), one phone, one app deal for the developer of that app. Is there a way of logging in without the OAuth dialog but by posting the username and pass to a FB url?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a quick browse through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), particularly the linked section; using signatures in posts is discouraged, because posts are "signed" with your user card. :)

Comment: I normally welcome criticism but since you have no thoughts on the matter at hand I find your intervention annoying, no harm intended.